# why does MS Sql Server not have active-active mirrors like other competing dbs?

Tags: sql-server

MS Sql has a fake active-active system. They are all active-passive or 'pretend' active-active, with no load balancing. You cant just throw in 10 sql servers with non shared storage, attach a load balancer, and gain 10x read/write performance and redundancy. Things like AWS Aurora support this out of the box. Why doesn't Sql offer something similar after decades?

Comment: This is a GREAT idea. You should post it on [Microsoft's feedback forum for SQL Server](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/04fe6ee0-3b25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0). Make sure you update your question with a link to the feedback item.

Comment: Seems like you might have a misunderstanding of the features available on SQL Server and perhaps should do some more research and experimentation before posing such a blunt question. In short, Load Balancing and *true* Active-Active data synchronization does exist among the many data synchronization features available in SQL Server. If after you research those features and have a question specific to one of them, then your question may be better suited here. Or if you want to ask a question regarding your end goals, then the appropriate features can be suggested to achieve them.

Comment: In addition to editing your question to be more focused, it will be more likely to be re-opened if you change the tone to be less like a rant.

Comment: im sorry ive been searching for years for a solution. just frustrated. i created another question which is less a rant. thanks for the info about Transactional Replication.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has Merge Replication, you can read and write on both Publisher and Subscriber sides:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication?view=sql-server-ver15

If Merge Replication does not have load balancing, it doesn't mean it is "fake active active system". It just does not have kind of load balancing you want, however you can still set up your apps so they use all nodes

> Why doesn't Sql offer something similar after decades?

Because MSSQL's biggest customers who bring most money to MS, did not ask for that feature you want ?  If they did, believe me SQL Server could already do what you described

Comment: Peer-to-Peer Transactional Replication and Transactional Publication with Updatable Subscriptions are two other Active-Active features as well. But I didn't feel OP's question warranted an answer with how unfocussed it was.

Comment: im sorry ive been searching for years for a solution. just frustrated. i created another question which is less a rant. thanks for the info about Transactional Replication.

Comment: @Luke happens. Please vote up and mark as answer if you find my above answer useful. I will try to write an answer for your another question, later this evening. Have something to share

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard about SQL server's AlwaysOn? It might meet some of your requirements and answer your questions.

Comment: AO is confusing. But Transactional Replication seems to do everything anyone could want. Hopefully doesnt require AD.